# Merging Multiple Core Data Models (xcdatamodels) Into One Project By Hand

Tags: iphone, core-data, merge

Hey guys, so I have a team of iOS developers, who each are working on a separate portion of the app, we are all using Xcode version 3.2.x. Now it is time for me to combine all of our work into one project, this entails be merging all the .xcdatamodels into one Xcode project. I thought I would be able to merely copy and paste the models into the data model viewer, however I was wrong. Anyone know of a fast, trivial way to do this? I really rather not recreate each person's model by hand... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out, it is possible via copying and pasting. Use the table windows view at the upper part of the model editor to select exactly what you want to copy and when pasting in new entities be sure to have nothing selected otherwise it won't paste it. That was the difficulty I was initially experiencing.